# Obtain Virtual IP - Azure App Service Environment

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service, virtual-ip-address

I am trying to setup **IP Based SSL** instead of **SNI SSL** on an azure Web App.

The App Service Plan is Standard S1, but unfortunately I am getting the following error message:
**There are no IP addresses in the App Service Environment that are available to be assigned to your app.**

What are the possible options?

I believe moving the current Web App to a different App Service Plan in a different resource group would solve this issue. I Have already tried moving the App service plan to a different resource group but failed.
[image: Clicking the button doesn't work]
*Note: Clicking the scale up button doesn't work and shows a JavaScript error in the console*

[image: JavaScript Error found in Chrome console]
JavaScript Error found in Chrome console

Comment: If possible can you share the console error you are seeing?

Comment: I have updated the post to include the error @ByronTardif

Comment: Thanks!, we'll look into that, in the meantime you should be able to use the workaround I suggested below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byron is correct that this is a bug in the UX.
A fix has been made and should be live later today.

Answer (score 2):

Your app is being hosted in an App Service Environment.

Looks like the scale up bottom is not working and that is probably a bug in the UX.

As a workaround you should be able to go directly to the App Service Environment that is hosting your app and perform the scale operation there.

once the scale operation in the App Service environment is done and the new IP Address is added, then you should be able to come back to the SSL binging UX in the app and try this again.